# Looking for efficient way to post thousands of HTTP request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post

I'm a newbie to JS/node.js coming from the .Net world.

I've got an existing Web API host, which I would like to stress test using various payloads. I know there are existing load test tools that would let me do that - this is not the point.

Currently, I'm looking for an efficient way to send thousands of POST requests as fast as possible.

Here is my attempt (which is a JS adapted C# version):

```
const useNode = false;
const request = useNode 
    ? require('request-promise-native') : require('axios');

const postRequest =  useNode ? postNode : postAxios;

const MaxBatchSize = 100;
const MaxRequests = 20000;
const MaxIterations = MaxRequests / MaxBatchSize;

(async () => {

    console.info('Going to send %i POST requests.', MaxRequests)
    console.info('Start time: %s', (new Date()).toTimeString());

    const hrstart = process.hrtime();

    for (var i = 0; i < MaxIterations; i++) {
        var promises = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < MaxBatchSize; j++) {
            promises[j] = postRequest();
        }

        await Promise.all(promises);
    }

    var hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);

    console.info('End time  : %s', (new Date()).toTimeString());
    console.info('Elapsed   : %ds %ims', hrend[0], hrend[1] / 1000000);
    console.info('Rate      : %i req/s', MaxRequests / (hrend[0] + hrend[1] / 1000000000));  
})();

// Use with 'axios'
function postAxios() {
    return request.post('http://192.168.1.106:9000/api/reports/new', {
        Hash: 'payload',
        Count: 22       
    });
}

// Use with 'request-promise-native'
function postNode() {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://192.168.1.106:9000/api/reports/new',
        body: {
            Hash: 'payload',
            Count: 22
        },
        json: true
    };

    return request(options);    
}
```

I get decent results on my development workstation, but the rate or requests per second is way lower compared to the original C# version (e.g. 3000/s vs 8000/s).

So, my question is whether this is expected or I should do it differently to maximize the rate.

[I'm not posting to spark X vs Z holly war! I really want to find the most efficient way.]

Comment: have you tried using Bluebird.map (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) instead of promise.all ?

Comment: @Ganesh, I have not tried it. I've chosen the current version as everything seemed very simple and intuitive. I'll try to use your advice and see the results.

Comment: @Ganesh, I gave the 'bluebird' a try. Assuming I did it properly, the results are the same as when I use 'request-promise-native' or 'axios'.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach that pops into my mind is to run several instances of this process simultaneously.  If one instance can churn out 3,000 requests, then it stands to reason that two of them working together would develop 6,000 requests and so on.  (And the request pattern would be that much more unpredictable.)

Comment: I've followed your advice and used `require('cluster')` with `fork()` based on the number of CPUs. Indeed, it improved the rate from ~3K/s to ~6.8K/s (of course I did not expect it to be linear). Just for comparison, I did the same with C# (i.e. running parallel processes, one per available CPU) and this increased the rate from ~8K to ~10.5K/s. Still, I would not expect to see such a gap on a vanilla code that does not do any computation.